# How can I resolve the error when loading a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, keras

I am presenting the following error when trying to load the keras model that I have saved in a JSON file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-68-5a5e2a8306d9> in <cell line: 88>()
         86 best_last = config.get('testing settings', 'best_last')
         87 #Load the saved model
    ---> 88 model = model_from_json(open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/retina-unet-         master/test/test_architecture.json').read())
         89 model.load_weights('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/retina-unet-  master/test/test_best_weights.h5')
         90 

    7 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py in process_node(layer,     node_data)
       1387         input_tensors = []
       1388         for input_data in tf.nest.flatten(node_data):
    -> 1389             input_data = input_data.as_list()
       1390             if len(input_data) == 3:
       1391                 kwargs = {}

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'as_list'
```

The error code line is as follows:

```
model = model_from_json(open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/retina-unet-master/test/test_architecture.json').read())
```

I have tried other variants to upload the file, but I continue with the same problem, I need help please